# Extract substring from a string using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to javascript, How to extract substring that matches a regex in a string in javascript?

For example in python:

```
version_regex =  re.compile(r'(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)')
line = "[2021-05-29] Version 2.24.9"
found = version_regex.search(line)
if found:
  found.group() // It will give the substring that macth with regex in this case 2.24.9
```

I tried these in javascript:

```
let re = new RegExp('^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)$');
let x = line.match(re);
```

but I am not getting the version here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `new RegExp` if you're not constructing the regexp dynamically. Use a RegExp literal.

Comment: The reason it's not working is because you need to escape the backslashes in the string. You wouldn't have that problem if you used a literal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`RegExp.prototype.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) which returns an `Array` with the full match and the capturing groups matches:

```js
const input = '[2021-05-29] Version 2.24.9';

const regex = /(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/;

let x = regex.exec(input);

console.log(x);
```