# How to Split String in React Js?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to extract "GoogleUpdate.exe" from the string "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe"?

Comment: RegEx could help, or String.split()

Comment: React does not provide such functionality. You should check JavaScript string methods documentation, there's one for split.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract substring from a string using regex in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68878912/extract-substring-from-a-string-using-regex-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with a combination of `split()` and `pop()`:

```js
const str = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Update\\GoogleUpdate.exe";
const parts = str.split("\\");
const fileName = parts.pop();

console.log(fileName); // outputs "GoogleUpdate.exe"
```

> Note: You would need to escape the `\` character

Answer (score 0):

It can be extracted from the given string by using the following steps:

Split the string by "". This will create an array of strings where each element is separated by a backslash.

Take the last element of the array, which is "GoogleUpdate.exe".

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Example = () => {
const [string, setString] = useState("C:\\Program Files 
(x86)\\Google\\Update\\GoogleUpdate.exe");
const splitString = string.split("\\");
const extracted = splitString[splitString.length - 1];

return (
<div>
  <p>Original String: {string}</p>
  <p>Extracted String: {extracted}</p>
</div>
);
};

export default Example;
```

Comment: It's undefined to access negative index in JS.

Comment: You're correct, accessing a negative index in JavaScript can result in an "undefined" value. To safely extract "GoogleUpdate.exe" from the string "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe", I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, character '\' is a escape character!
so, if you write your code lolike this:

```js
const tmp = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe";
console.log(tmp);
```

you will be got result

```
C:Program Files (x86)GoogleUpdateGoogleUpdate.exe
```

if you want keep '\' in your variable, you can manual fix

```js
const tmp = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Update\\GoogleUpdate.exe";
```

actualy, it's not smart,maybe string template literals is better.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw

```js
const tmp = String.raw`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe`
console.log(tmp);
tmp.split('\\').pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Split Method:

```js
import React from 'react';

function Example() {
  const path = "C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe";
  const filename = path.split('\').pop();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>The filename is: {filename}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Example;
```